# "I wouldn't bother writing this email if I {didn't / don't} treasure our friendship"

Tags: subjunctives, infinitive-vs-gerund

> I wouldn't bother **writing** (or **to write**) this email if I **didn't** (*or* **don't**) treasure our friendship and by all means want to mend it.

I'd like to know if you'd use

1. *didn't* or *don't*, and why;
2. *bother writing* or *bother to write*,  and why.

Answer (score 1):

I won't bother writing (or to write) if I don't treasure our friendship. (1st conditional)

I wouldn't bother writing (or to write) if I didn't treasure our friendship. (2nd conditional)

Answer (score 0):

1. "Didn't" is the correct form. The word wouldn't (would not) is past tense and so you should use didn't (did not) so they agree. "Don't" (do not) is present tense.
2. Either is grammatically correct, you can pick which term you prefer.

Comment: "wouldn't" is not past tense.